# Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0034' when trying to add image

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I am not a coder, and am working on an old asp site, and there is a page to upload images to given page (from a dropdown list), but when I try to add images to the corresponding page I get this error, which I guess has been there since the beginning.

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0034'
Bad file name or number
/path-to-file/foto.asp, line 105

The relevant code is this

```
'Create and Write to a File
Randomize()
strChiave = Cstr(Right(DatePart("yyyy", Date()),2))
strChiave = strChiave + Cstr(DatePart("y", Date()))
strChiave = strChiave + Replace(Time(),".","")
strChiave = strChiave + Right(Session.SessionID,4)
strChiave = strChiave + CSTR(INT(RND()*1000))
strImmagine = strChiave + Right(filename,4)
Set MyFile = ScriptObject.CreateTextFile(Application("path_public") & "/" & strImmagine)

For i = 1 to LenB(value)
MyFile.Write chr(AscB(MidB(value,i,1)))
Next
MyFile.Close
```

Line 105 is this

```
Set MyFile = ScriptObject.CreateTextFile(Application("path_public") & "/" & strImmagine)
```

Thank you

Comment: Put a `response.write(path_public)` to your code, before line 105 and see results. This can help you identify if the path of your image is correct.

Comment: Check the value of `strImmagine` as well.

Comment: Thank you both. putting response.write(path_public) just changes the line number (now 106). Like said I am not a coder, anyhow I can see only 3 instances of strImmagine, two are in the snip in OP, the other is few lines lower, and is this: strSQL = strSQL + strImmagine + "', '"

Comment: the foto.asp is in a folder (admin), and the images are in (public), there are images in there that do display on site, but I don't know if they were loaded thru ftp, or what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Time()` method returns time with such structure: `HH:mm` where "HH" is the hour, and "mm" the minutes. As you see, it contains a colon character, not a dot and colon is not valid inside file path.

Change this line in your code:

```
strChiave = strChiave + Replace(Time(),".","")
```

To this instead:

```
strChiave = strChiave + Replace(Time(),":","")
```

Comment: Thank you. Now the error is: Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0046'
Permission denied. Same line, I did q quick search, but there seems to be different solutions, and don't know which one is my case; I am testing it on local (win8.1 IIS).

Comment: @keneso before the line starting with `Set MyFile = ScriptObject.CreateTextFile` add this line: `Response.Write("<div>path: " & Application("path_public") & "/" & strImmagine & "</div>")` and let me know what you see when running the code

Comment: Thank you. This is what is reported, plus the error posted in previous comment. path: C:\Users\Mypc\sites\A-ASP_sites\fioriera\public/1659163834380859.png

Comment: Anyhow, I tested your suggestion of changing colon, and dot, on the live environment, and it works, hence it is something about my local IIS settings, which is not vital at this point.

Comment: It means that on your local machine the path `C:\Users\Mypc\sites\A-ASP_sites\fioriera\public` is probably not under the site root, so classic ASP doesn't have permissions there. Glad you got it sorted on the live environment!